# Same if statement in collision detection doesn't work w/ different variables

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm trying to detect if the player has hit the block, and if so, stopping them of course (e.g. if it hits a wall on the left it can't move left). So it works fine, I've done the collision for up and down, but for some reason when I go on to do the collision for the left side (the last if statement) the player is able to just move through the block and I can't figure out why, because the if statement is basically the same.

FYI: pX is the x co-ordinate of the player,
     pY is the y co-ordinate of the player, 
     XnY[1] is the y co-ordinate of the block,
     XnY[0] is the x co - ordinate of the block,
     playerSize is it's a square, so 50x50

```
    level =  ["W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W","W",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",                                       
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",                                     
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","P","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L",
              "N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","L","S"]    
blockXY = []

    for element in level:
        if element == "N":
             x += block_width
        if element == "L":                                              
             y += block_height
             x = 0
        if element == "P": 
            drawBlock(block_width,block_height,x,y)                
            blockXY.append(x)
            blockXY.append(y)
            if appendBlockXY:
                if len(collisionArray) > P_count:
                    del(collisionArray[P_count])
                    print(collisionArray)
                    appendBlockXY = False
                collisionArray.append(blockXY)
            blockXY = []
            x += block_width
        if element == "S":
            y = 0


for XnY in collisionArray

        if pX >= XnY[0] and pX <= XnY[0] + block_width or pX + playerSize >= XnY[0] and pX <= XnY[0] + block_width:

            if pY - block_height == XnY[1]:
                canMoveUp = False
                y_change = 0

        if pX >= XnY[0] and pX <= XnY[0] + block_width or pX + playerSize >= XnY[0] and pX <= XnY[0] + block_width:

            if XnY[1] - playerSize == pY:
                canMoveDown = False
                y_change = 0

        if pY >= XnY[1] and pY <= XnY[1] + block_height or pY +  playerSize >= XnY[1] and pY + playerSize <= XnY[1] + block_height:

            if pX - block_width == XnY[0]:
                canMoveLeft = False
                y_change = 0
```

Comment: Can you add how you defined collisionArray ?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention collisionArray is just defined at the beginning of the code as an empty list, then stuff gets added to it as shown in the code

Comment: use `print` to see what values you have - maybe there are different values than you expect.

Comment: yeh it seems that it stops me from moving only if I stop at exactly the border of the block

Comment: but if I hold the left arrow key it just moves through the block, but if I position myself exactly on the block it stops me. I find it weird because w/ my other two if statements if I run into them it stops me immediatly

Comment: basically if you are already moving when you come in contact with the block you pass through it (this is if you are moving in from the left side) but if you stop directly on the border you stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! It was a silly mistake on my part, instead of writing y_change = 0 it should have been x_change = 0. Ooops!